# How to Decipher Ambiguous Unity C# Stack Trace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, crash, stack-trace

Sometimes I experience crashes on an Android device, and when I go to look at the logs to see what the cause is, the stack trace doesn't wind up being too helpful. Usually what I get is the last line to calls out in my code is just the last line of the function/method block; e.g. the line with the closing curly brace on it. And the stack trace line prior to that is just the line number of the very first line in the method/function block.

After that, the stack trace is pretty much vague jibberish. Is there any hope trying to decipher a stack trace like this?

backtrace:

```
#00  pc 0004b540  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01  pc 00048c43  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
#02  pc 0001e221  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03  pc 002a2bc8  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#04  pc 002a2cc4  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#05  pc 002a2d20  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#06  pc 00116e3c  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#07  pc 001170d8  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#08  pc 0011774c  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#09  pc 001262f4  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#10  pc 000eb020  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#11  pc c7d80054  <unknown/absolute>
#12  il ........  at WorldObject.evaluate_position () [0x00031] in /Volumes/JenkinsRAID/Jenkins/workspace/Game(Debug)/Assets/Scripts/WorldObjects/WorldObject.cs:225
#13  il 00000028  at WorldObjec.evaluate_position () [0x0000d] in /Volumes/JenkinsRAID/Jenkins/workspace/Game(Debug)/Assets/Scripts/WorldObjects/WorldObject.cs:218
#14  il 00000073  at WidgetMapSocket.on_world_object_pathing_complete_listener (WorldObject) [0x0003b] in /Volumes/JenkinsRAID/Jenkins/workspace/Game(Debug)/Assets/Scripts/UI/Widgets/Map/WidgetMapSocket.cs:1031
#15  il 00000063  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Action`1<WorldObject>.invoke_void__this___WorldObject (WorldObject) <IL 0x00042, 0x00063>
#16  il 0000008f  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Action`1<WorldObject>.invoke_void__this___WorldObject (WorldObject) <IL 0x00056, 0x0008f>
#17  il 00000073  at WorldObject.on_pathing_complete (WorldObject) [0x00031] in /Volumes/JenkinsRAID/Jenkins/workspace/Game(Debug)/Assets/Scripts/WorldObjects/WorldObject.cs:605
#18  il 000000a3  at GameHelper.exec<object> (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<System.Action`1<object>>,object) [0x00032] in /Volumes/JenkinsRAID/Jenkins/workspace/Game(Debug)/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GameHelper.cs:236
#19  il 00000413  at WorldObject/<pathing_coroutine>c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x0022a] in /Volumes/JenkinsRAID/Jenkins/workspace/Game(Debug)/Assets/Scripts/WorldObjects/WorldObject.cs:816
#20  il 00000067  at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr) [0x00028] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17
#21  il 0000007b  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00022, 0x0007b>
#00  pc 000222fb  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so
#01  pc 001f6054  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_runtime_invoke+136)
#02  pc 008c8858  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+84)
#03  pc 008a817c  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (Coroutine::InvokeMoveNext(ScriptingExceptionPtr*)+164)
#04  pc 008a7d4c  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (Coroutine::Run(bool*)+44)
#05  pc 003e7490  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (DelayedCallManager::Update(int)+864)
#06  pc 0063a4fc  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (InitPlayerLoopCallbacks()::UpdateScriptRunDelayedDynamicFrameRateRegistrator::Forward()+40)
#07  pc 0063adf8  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (PlayerLoop()+1716)
#08  pc 00a11904  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+856)
#09  pc 00a13ecc  /data/app/com.company.game/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+228)
```

Comment: Does `Assets/Scripts/WorldObjects/WorldObject.cs:225` tell you anything?

Comment: No, as mentioned in the original post, line 225 in WorldObject is nothing but the line with the closing brace for the function method body. That is literally the only char on the entire line.